# How to find the vector equation of the line of the intersection of two planes $2x-y-3z=7$ and $x+2y+2z=0$?

Tags: vectors

We need to find the vector equation of the line of intersection of the above mentioned planes. I'm not that good with vectors so couldn't understand how to do it even though I had the answer in the mark scheme.

Here's the answer:

[image]

Edit: Turns out my answer is right. I will copy this and post it as an answer so if someone else has a similar question, I can help them.

Comment: it is right, you find a parametrization of the ligne, it is clear that the vector line is $(- \frac {4}{7}, 1, -\frac {5}{7})$.

Comment: But isn't my answer wrong?

Comment: I said it is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x= \frac {7+y+3z}{2}$$ and $x= -2y-2z$ [rearranging the two equations of $p_1$ and $p_2$]

$$7+y+3z = -4y-4z$$

$$z = \frac {-5y-7}{7}$$

After plugging in this value of $z$ in the first equation for $x$, I got $x= \frac {14-4y}{7}$

Let $y = t$

$$x= \frac {14-4t}{7}$$

$$z= \frac {-7-5t}{7}$$

This gives the equation of the line to be $(2, 0, -1) + t(- \frac {4}{7}, 1, -\frac {5}{7})$ [by separating the $t$ terms and then taking $t$ common]